# AMPscript RetrieveSalesforceObjects - Retrieve a specific row for a subscriber

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect

I am looking to use AMPscript to insert a personalization string in an email using RetrieveSalesforceObjects.  Specifically, I want to get data from a subscriber's corresponding contact record (using MC Connect and the SF ID is our subscriber key).  I've seen a few examples but not this specific one so I was hoping perhaps someone could confirm that what I've written below is the appropriate way to accomplish this?

```
    %%[
    var @id,@Contacts,@row,@studentID

    Set @id = _subscriberkey
    Set @Contacts = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Contact', 'SIS_Student_ID__c', 'Id', '=', @id)
    Set @row = ROW(@Contacts,1)
    Set @studentID = FIELD(@row, 'SIS_Student_ID__c')
]%%

%%=FormatNumber(v(@studentID),"G","en-US")=%% /*personalization string to be used in body of email*/
```

Comment: use like this %%=formatnumber(@studentID,"G", "en-US")=%%

Comment: What error you getting ?

Comment: Hello @pkharries , I'm not getting an error - I just wanted to make sure that my methodology was correct so that I don't send the wrong data to the wrong person.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A better approach is doing something like this

```
%%[

var @contactStudents

set @contactStudents = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
   "Contact",
   "SIS_Student_ID__c",
   "Id",
   "=",
   _subscriberKey )

/* Only one row is returned as we are doing equals comparision for matching  */
if RowCount(@contactStudents) == 1 then 

  var @prospectRow, @stuId, @stuIdformatted

  set @prospectRow   = Row(@contactStudents, 1)
  set @stuId         = Field(@prospectRow, "SIS_Student_ID__c")
  set @stuIdformatted= FormatNumber(@stuId,"G","en-US")

endif

]%%
```

And personalise body of your email with

```
%%=v(@stuIdformatted)=%%
```

Comment: I'm using same syntax yet the RetrieveSalesforceObjects is returning zero records, I'm querying a custom object. am I missing something?